# How to read a file and store it's content in a matrix in C?

Tags: c

I am familliar to C++ but now I have to work with C.
I need to read a file in C and assign it's content to matrix, let's say `a[20][20]`.
It is possible? I have a file containing a list of aliments one alliment on each line and want to sort it alphabetically and add 1), 2), 3) for each aliment in order. Like "1)carrots", "2)milk", "3)water".

```
char a[20][20]
FILE *file;
file=fopen("test.txt","r");
a = file; //(incorrect but you get the point)
```

Comment: Hi Robert , in C lang , array is constant address so you can't update it with invalid as well as valid address .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
        char a[20][20],str[20];
        int i;
        FILE *file;
        file=fopen("./test.txt","r");
        if(file == NULL)
                printf("FILE NOT Opened...\n");
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
                if(fgets(str, 20, file) != NULL)
                {
                        strcpy(a[i], str);
                        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
                }
        }
}
```

`test.txt` File content are

```
apple
rat
lion
rabbit
butterfly
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question. How I can determine how many words I have in that file?

Comment: use  int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...); function in while loop with one counter , it will return EOF when file ends(words ends).  like while(fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)  != EOF){ counter++}